# iOS zooms my webpage

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

This is frustrating and I have seen and tried many answers but still end up with a zoomed effect on my webpage when I view on iOS. I have experimented with various viewport settings but the initial view is always zoomed.

Here is the experimental link. The page has a fixed header and footer and looks and functions fine in web browsers but in iOS it looks zoomed in. If I double tap, it resumes the desired view.

http://jbrubaker.fatcow.com/dealer/index2.html

Viewport settings:

Is it a CSS issues?

A fixed element issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some screenshots? I don't see anything strange. iOS of the devices where you tested?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using UIWebView to view the site.

Set the BOOLEAN [scalesPageToFit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scalesPageToFit) property of your UIWebView to **YES**.

This would hopefully solve your issue. If not then get back with your comments

Comment: I am viewing the site in Safari Mobile.